# Global variable not updating inside static Class method in PHP

Tags: php, global-variables, superglobals

I have a problem with global variables in PHP. My problem is that a global variable that I change inside a static class method isn't updating outside the method.

I've included the code:

test.php

```
define( 'APP_ID', 'TESTING' );
$_APP = array( 'test' => 'test value' );
include ('appsettings.class.php');
AppSettings::initApplication();
```

appsettings.class.php

```
class AppSettings
{
  public static function initApplication()
  {
    global $_APP;
    session_start();

    // Some code here for your initializtions
    self::initAppEngine();
echo '<pre>Inside initApplication: '; print_r($_APP);
echo '<pre>Directly printing the session variable: '; print_r($_SESSION[APP_ID] );
  }

  private static function initAppEngine()
  {
    global $_APP;

    if( isset($_SESSION[APP_ID]) )
    {
      $_APP = &$_SESSION[APP_ID];
    }
    else
    {
      $_SESSION[APP_ID] = array( 'abcd' => 'hello', 'APP_ID' => APP_ID );
      $_APP = &$_SESSION[APP_ID];
die("Refresh the page");
    }

    if ( !isset( $_APP['uid'] ) )
      $_APP['uid'] = 0;

echo '<pre>Inside initAppEngine: '; print_r($_APP);
  }
}
```

The old value of $_APP is coming instead of the new one inside initApplication. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite interesting. First of all, note that it seems to have nothing to do with static methods:

```
$_SESSION['test'] = array("test value from superglobal");
$_APP = array('test' => "test value directly assigned");

class AppSettings
{
  public static function initApplication()
  {
    global $_APP;
    $_APP = &$_SESSION['test'];
    echo '<pre>Inside initApplication: '; print_r($_APP);
  }

  public function initApplicationNonStatic()
  {
    global $_APP;
    $_APP = &$_SESSION['test'];
    echo '<pre>Inside initApplicationNonStatic: '; print_r($_APP);
  }
}

echo '<pre>Before calling initApplication: '; print_r($_APP);
AppSettings::initApplication();
echo '<pre>After calling initApplication: '; print_r($_APP);
echo '<pre>Before calling initApplicationNonStatic: '; print_r($_APP);
$appSettings = new AppSettings();
$appSettings->initApplicationNonStatic();
echo '<pre>After calling initApplicationNonStatic: '; print_r($_APP);
```

Result:

```
Before calling initApplication: Array
(
    [test] => test value directly assigned
)
Inside initApplication: Array
(
    [0] => test value from superglobal
)
After calling initApplication: Array
(
    [test] => test value directly assigned
)
Before calling initApplicationNonStatic: Array
(
    [test] => test value directly assigned
)
Inside initApplicationNonStatic: Array
(
    [0] => test value from superglobal
)
After calling initApplicationNonStatic: Array
(
    [test] => test value directly assigned
)
```

But this works:

```
$_SESSION['test'] = array("test value from superglobal");
$_APP = array('test' => "test value directly assigned");

class AppSettings2
{
  public function initApplicationNonStatic()
  {
    $GLOBALS['_APP'] = &$_SESSION['test']; // by reference
    echo '<pre>Inside initApplicationNonStatic: '; print_r($GLOBALS['_APP']);
  }
}

echo '<pre>Before calling initApplicationNonStatic: '; print_r($_APP);
$appSettings2 = new AppSettings2();
$appSettings2->initApplicationNonStatic();
echo '<pre>After calling initApplicationNonStatic: '; print_r($_APP);
$_SESSION['test'] = array("test value from superglobal altered");
echo '<pre>After altering superglobal: '; print_r($_APP);
```

Result:

```
Before calling initApplicationNonStatic: Array
(
    [test] => test value directly assigned
)
Inside initApplicationNonStatic: Array
(
    [0] => test value from superglobal
)
After calling initApplicationNonStatic: Array
(
    [0] => test value from superglobal
)
After altering superglobal: Array
(
    [0] => test value from superglobal altered
)
```

And this works, too:

```
$_SESSION['test'] = array("test value from superglobal");
$_APP = array('test' => "test value directly assigned");

class AppSettings2
{
  public function initApplicationNonStatic()
  {
    global $_APP;
    $_APP = $_SESSION['test']; // by value
    echo '<pre>Inside initApplicationNonStatic: '; print_r($_APP);
  }
}

echo '<pre>Before calling initApplicationNonStatic: '; print_r($_APP);
$appSettings2 = new AppSettings2();
$appSettings2->initApplicationNonStatic();
echo '<pre>After calling initApplicationNonStatic: '; print_r($_APP);
$_SESSION['test'] = array("test value from superglobal altered");
echo '<pre>After altering superglobal: '; print_r($_APP);
```

Result:

```
Before calling initApplicationNonStatic: Array
(
    [test] => test value directly assigned
)
Inside initApplicationNonStatic: Array
(
    [0] => test value from superglobal
)
After calling initApplicationNonStatic: Array
(
    [0] => test value from superglobal
)
After altering superglobal: Array
(
    [0] => test value from superglobal // expected, since assigned by value
)
```

So, it seems that whenever you want to assign a **reference** to a global variable inside a function or method, you have to use the `$GLOBALS['_APP']` syntax and you cannot use `global $_APP`. If you don't need the assignment by reference, `$GLOBALS['_APP']` and `global $_APP` behave the same.

I'm not exactly sure why this is so; [some](http://www.elated.com/articles/php-references/) [pages](http://code.stephenmorley.org/php/references-tutorial/) refer to the equivalence of these two constructs:

```
global $example;
$example =& $GLOBALS['example'];
```

This might lead to the right track; however, I hope that you can troubleshoot your problem with my answer.

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks! I had tried using $_GLOBALS but I'm not sure why it hadn't worked when I had tried it. My only concern right now with the above technique is that I need the $_APP to work inside my other functions also (though I won't be needing the assign by reference). I am going to check if it works like I want it to. Either way, thanks for the great answer!

Comment: Not very familiar with replying on StackOverflow, sorry about the multiple comments. Do you think I should file a bug report because we shouldn't have to use $_GLOBALS? And also, thanks for the links (very helpful to understand references).

Comment: I think you need a certain amount of reputation to edit your comments. :-) Please be sure to use `$GLOBALS` instead of `$_GLOBALS` (but I guess that's a typo). As for filing a bug, I'm not sure, I think this behaviour might be intended or rather an effect of the implementation of PHP itself, especially since you should think that more people should have run into it in the past. Perhaps it makes sense, though I cannot see why so far. Perhaps you can get in contact with someone from the PHP dev team without filing a bug right away? Not sure what's the best approach.